# How to update the marker position on google map by latitude and longitude values

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am new to iOS Swift. I recently started working on `GMSMaps`. In my code I am able to get the `latitude` and `longitude` values of source and destination to find the direction and I am also able to add the marker to map. But, I want to change the position of marker based on changing the source and destination values. When I tried to change source/destination ,then again one more marker is adding to maps. I don't want to add one more marker, I just want to move the previous marker to updated location . If any one gives solution it would be so great.

This is my code which I have written to add marker for source and destination. I have written this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of tableView

```
let centerr = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 10);
self.googlemapsview.camera = camera
var marker = GMSMarker(position: centerr)
print("Latitude :- \(lat)")
print("Longitude :-\(lon)")
marker.map = self.googlemapsview
```

Comment: Clear map and add marker with lat long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `marker` as global variable and update its coordinates via position property.

```
var marker: GMSMarker!
```

Update marker:

```
let newPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLat, longitude: newLon)
marker.position = newPosition
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#a2b9fdae0160d7acf439889ffcdb5f68b

in `tableViewDidSelect`

```
let centerr = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 10);
self.googlemapsview.camera = camera
marker = GMSMarker(position: centerr)
print("Latitude :- \(lat)")
print("Longitude :-\(lon)")
marker.map = self.googlemapsview
```